# Compute list of dask delayed object

Tags: python, dask, delayed-execution, dask-delayed, dask-ml

I have gone all similar question and solutions provided, but not getting desired output.

I have a list of dask delayed objects.

```
for y in ys:
   projection = Projection(data, X, y)
   fi = projection.decode()
   var.append(fi)
```

where Projection class and decode method are following:

```
class Projection(object):

    def __init__(self, data, X, y=0): 
# data is dataframe, X is indecies of independent variables and y is index of dependent variable
        self.data = data
        self.X = X
        self.y = y

    ...
    ...

    @dask.delayed
    def decode(self) -> list:

        regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50, max_features='sqrt', n_jobs=-1, max_depth=6, verbose=0)
        regressor.fit(self.X, self.y)
        fi = regressor.feature_importances_
        return fi
```

Var is:

```
[Delayed('decode-82afe417-9d1e-48ff-95a3-02ddc90c6970'), 
Delayed('decode-0a872626-996a-4a19-8b45-b39acb44257f'), 
Delayed('decode-cfa53fd4-cf5b-47f1-a672-440dc5f5ca35'), 
Delayed('decode-29cf7f51-2e7a-4c9d-8ac0-bc2259d50b6f'), 
Delayed('decode-2edc8324-f9df-4402-a1ed-44a6a9067f1d'), 
Delayed('decode-05de7417-49a5-40b7-8098-f2aad50bd934'), 
Delayed('decode-80916f08-2d28-4811-9ab4-e526af978aac'), 
Delayed('decode-da4a8874-77b5-4d75-aede-c96b5e73e888'), 
Delayed('decode-1c1fe7f0-a32b-4a0a-9d13-bb45710a3738')
```

Now I want to compute this *var* and want to get a list or array or data frame. For that purpose, I tried various options:

**option1**

```
dask.compute(*var)
```

**option2**

```
v = dask.array.from_array(np.array(var), chunks=(100,))
dask.array.compute(*v)
```

**option3**

```
v = dask.array.from_delayed(np.array(var))
dask.array.compute(*v)
```

**option4**

```
v = dask.array.from_delayed(np.array(var))
v.compute()
```

but in all cases, either I get again the list of delayed objects or time out.

Option-1 giving following error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 458. MiB for an array with shape (19971, 3005) and data type int64
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 appears to be the most appropriate one, Options 3 and 4 will result in a list of delayed objects because in those options `v` contains nested delayed objects.

It would help to know more details about the setup (local/distributed), data magnitude, computation intensity, and the activity on the dask dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. 
But, This is giving following error:

numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 458. MiB for an array with shape (19971, 3005) and data type int64

I have added further details also in the query.

Comment: Hmm, are you running this on a laptop or a low-spec machine? It seems that your workers are running out of memory...

Comment: No. 

<Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:36828' processes=8 threads=40, memory=201.40 GB>

Comment: Can you try setting setting threads to a lower number? Do you get the same error if you use 8 threads?

Comment: Thanks. By reducing the nThreads to 4, it is started working fine